# Which tokens can be borrowed from dYdX?

Tags: flash-loans

Is there a list of tokens that can be borrowed from dYdX for a flashloan? I assume it can be any of their supported Ethereum tokens but I'm having troubles finding a complete list of what they support.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unfortunately dYdX discontinued SoloMargin](https://dydx.exchange/blog/layer-1-wind-down), and therefore their ability to carry out flashloans as of Nov, 2021. So no tokens can be borrowed anymore for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Only 4 tokens: DAI, USDC, WETH and SAI

This is how you can get this list:

```
     pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
    import "hardhat/console.sol";
    import { SafeMath } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
    import { IERC20 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
    import { ISoloMargin } from "./ISoloMargin.sol";
    import { ICallee } from "./ICallee.sol";
    import { DYDXDataTypes } from "./DYDXDataTypes.sol";

contract DYDX is ICallee {

      ISoloMargin public immutable soloMargin;
        address _soloMargin = 0x1E0447b19BB6EcFdAe1e4AE1694b0C3659614e4e;
         soloMargin = ISoloMargin(_soloMargin);
                // Setup state variables
                uint256 numMarkets = ISoloMargin(_soloMargin).getNumMarkets();
                console.log(numMarkets);
                for (uint256 marketId = 0; marketId < numMarkets; marketId++) {
                    address token = ISoloMargin(_soloMargin).getMarketTokenAddress(marketId);
                    tokenAddressToMarketId[token] = marketId;
                    console.log(token);
                }

}
```